# Что за синтаксическая конструкция?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Хорошая техника, выносливость, развитое тактическое мышление - Сергей мог бы добиться успеха в боксе, если бы не травма.

***Хорошая техника, выносливость, развитое тактическое мышление*** - это какая синтаксическая конструкция? Можно ли здесь говорить о **препозитивных** номинативах, называющих отличительные черты (по аналогии с постпозитивными номинативами)? Или препозитивные номинативы - это только именительные темы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что это именно **изолированный номинатив в препозиции,** хотя его вряд ли можно назвать именительным темы (изолированные номинативы — это более широкое понятие).

Информация здесь делится на две части, связанные по смыслу причинно-следственными отношениями, поэтому между ними ставится тире.

Сравнить: **Имея хорошую технику, выносливость, развитое тактическое мышление, Сергей мог бы добиться успеха в боксе, если бы не травма.**

**Книжная синтаксическая конструкция заменяется разговорной,** более краткой, выразительной, эмоциональной, и при этом семантика предложения остается вполне ясной для понимания.

https://studfiles.net/preview/2682296/

Comment: *Сравнить: Имея хорошую технику, выносливость, развитое тактическое мышление, Сергей мог бы добиться успеха в боксе, если бы не травма*. Все перевёрнуто с ног на голову. "Имея хорошую технику, Сергей мог бы..." – это означает, что *если бы* он имел хорошую технику, то добился бы успеха.

Comment: Здесь сослагательное наклонение.  Мог бы, если бы не травма. Избегайте разговорных конструкций вида "Все перевёрнуто с ног на голову", они  содержат негативную оценку в грубой форме.

Comment: Грубую форму вы сами сочинили, а негативная оценка – это правда.

Comment: Почему же правда? С такими качествами Сергей мог бы добиться успехов, если бы не травма. (Мог бы, но не добился) Это ирреальное  (контрфактическое) условие: придаточная часть сообщает об условии, которое не осуществилось (травма на самом деле была). Что Вы здесь нашли перевернутым с ног на голову?Объяснитесь, укажите ошибку, будьте так добры. Теперь я уже с нетерпением жду Вашего ответа, если Вы настаиваете на своем мнении.

Comment: Ещё раз: **Имея хорошую технику, Сергей мог бы добиться успеха** означает: **Если бы Сергей имел хорошую технику, он бы мог добиться успеха.** То есть смысл фразы перевернулся с ног на голову. Вы его перевернули.

Comment: Нет, неверно. Смысл такой;   Так как Сергей имел хорошую технику, то он мог бы добиться успеха, если бы ему не помешала травма. Кстати,сравните со вторым ответом, там тоже указаны отношения причина - следствие (так что).

Comment: Пожалуйста, в дальнейшем  сразу обозначайте мнение по спорным вопросам (что  не так и почему). У меня нет желания тратить время на долгие дискуссии,  различие в мнениях можно было определить сразу. Также, пожалуйста, старайтесь использовать нейтральный стиль речи, Вы же, наверное, знаете стилевые особенности, можете отличить вежливую фразу от невежливой.  Спасибо, рассчитываю на Ваше понимание.

Answer (score 1):

Это сложное предложение с разными видами связи; основная связь между двумя частями - *бессоюзная*. Первая часть - неполное двусоставное с однородными подлежащими, а вторая часть - сложноподчинённое предложение со значением вывода, следствия.

Ср.  ***[У него] хорошая техника, выносливость, развитое тактическое мышление — [так что] Сергей мог бы добиться успеха в боксе, если бы не травма.***

Дополнила ответ - уточнила вид предложения.

Comment: Неполные предложения  - это предложения, содержание которых восстанавливается по предыдущему тексту, а здесь обычный номинативный ряд.  Достраивать его и ПРЕВРАЩАТЬ В ДРУГУЮ конструкцию не нужно. Сравнить: Хорошая техника, выносливость, развитое тактическое мышление - у Сергея были все эти качества.  Это именительный темы. А в заданном предложении между номинативным рядом и второй частью причинно-следственные отношения, поэтому это изолированный номинатив.

Comment: А есть  ли у нас "предыдущий текст"? Наверняка есть. Но в вопросе не представлен. Никакого сомнения в том, что речь и в предыдущих предложениях идёт о Сергее, не возникает.

Comment: Обратите внимание: я не превращала предложение в другую конструкцию, оставила её прежней. Квадратными скобками я лишь объяснила свою позицию.

Comment: Получается. что Вы объясняете не заданное предложение, а Ваш собственный вариант со скобками. Первую часть нельзя считать двусоставным предложением, для этого нет никаких оснований.

Comment: Номинативных предложений нет, ибо номинативность предполагает бытийность, экзистенциальность. Именительного темы или именительного представления тоже нет, так как при данных словах нет поясняющей второй части. Если оставлять предложение в таком виде, то от номинативности надо уходить.

Comment: Изолированный номинатив и номинативные предложения - это абсолютно РАЗНЫЕ ВЕЩИ Я нигде в этой теме не упоминала термин "номинативные предложения". Вы почитайте материал о номинативах, который я даю в ссылке. Там они категорически различаются

Comment: Кстати о БСП.  1) Это предложение НЕ МОЖЕТ быть БСП, так как там есть подчинительная связь. 2) Предложение состоит из трех частей. Если считать, что тире обозначает бессоюзную связь, то она должна быть между 1 и 2+3. В действительности тире обозначает связь между 1 и 2, а подчинительная связь между 1+2 и 3. Вывод однозначный: это всё что угодно, но только  не БСП.

Comment: Я прекрасно различаю номинативные предложения и конструкции, сходные с ними))). Говоря о БСП, я называю его блоки - части (см.ответ) и основную связь между этими частями. Это бессоюзная связь. Часть сама по себе, конечно,  может быть отдельным предложением с союзной связью. И тогда это РВС. Тут я абсолютно с вами согласна, и не только я. Все мы видим союз "если бы не", присоединяющий придаточное к главному во второй части.

Comment: Хорошо. Если Вы  уже всё  и даже прекрасно знаете, а новых знаний Вам не нужно, то  дискуссию заканчиваем, у каждого остается свое мнение. Остановлюсь только на ФОРМАЛЬНОЙ  стороне Я считаю недопустимым называть конструкцию  БСП, если в ней есть два вида связи. В этом случае надо говорить так: это сложное предложение с подчинительной и бессоюзной связью. Но возможно, что  у Вас какая-то особая техника разбора. Впрочем, мне это уже неинтересно.

Comment: Новые знания я черпаю ежечасно!)  Вы правы: останемся пока каждая при своем мнении. Ответы читают люди грамотные, пусть выбирают то, что им ближе, понятнее. А мы немного поспорили, но в этом тоже нет ничего плохого: в споре рождается истина.